# Using angularjs with a static jsonp works only once

Tags: javascript, service, angularjs, jsonp, factory

I've got some data coming in from a jsonp file.

```
worm.factory('simpleFactory', function ($http, gf) {
var simpleFactory = "";
return {
    getJson: function ($scope) {
        var url = 'myfile.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
        $http.jsonp(url).success(function (data) {
                console.log("Got this", data);
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("Data not available");
            });

    }
}
});
```

which by itself runs fine in the page. However if the same app calls the query again OR the app is replicated further down the page (same data but different part of a graph) i get an error.

Given that it is a static json file, what can i do to over the problem? (or can i run the same app on the same page but isolated from each other?)

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method '_0'.

Note that i had to hard-wire .. angular.callbacks._0({".. into the jsonp file in order for it to even work once :-(

Comment: Why did you add the `angular.callbacks()` to the JSON payload? As far as I understand, you need not have to do this and the JSONP request should still work padding the payload with the `JSON_CALLBACK`?

Comment: Cause its a static file.

Answer (score 0):

First of all erase GF from the top if you are not calling it.
The correct way should be:

```
worm.factory('simpleFactory', function ($http) {
return {
    getJson: function (callback) {
        var url = 'myfile.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
        $http.jsonp(url).success(function (data) {
                callback(data);
        });

    }
}
});
```

Send callback to the function so your controller can recieve it.
I never used the $http.jsonp but the $http would be like this

```
worm.factory('simpleFactory', function ($http) {
return {
    getJson: function (callback) {
        var url = 'myfile.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
        $http({method: 'jsonp', url: 'myfile.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK'}).success(function (data) {
                callback(data);
        });

    }
}
});
```

It would help better if you post your controller and view to see if you are doing everthing correctly

Hope to hlep